# How to get more metrics(Threads count, Handles Count) other than the compute metrics offered by oracle cloud for an instance?

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I launched the windows instance. I found the config.yml file in the oracle cloud agent folder under program files.

**config.yml** file looks like below

```
telemetry:
endpoint_format: 'https://telemetry-ingestion.{}.oraclecloud.com'
endpoint_path: /20180401/metrics
submission_headers:
accept: application/json
content-type: application/json
get_headers:
accept: application/json
metrics:
- friendly_name: CPU Utilization
    name: CpuUtilization
    unit: Percent
    min_range: 0
    max_range: 100
- friendly_name: Memory Utilization
    name: MemoryUtilization
    unit: Percent
    min_range: 0
    max_range: 100
.
.
.
- friendly_name: Thread Count
    name: ThreadCount
    unit: Count
perfmon:
    metrics:
    - path: \Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time
      telemetry_metric_name: CpuUtilization
      type: double
    - path: \Memory\% Committed Bytes In Use
      telemetry_metric_name: MemoryUtilization
      type: double
    .
    .
    .
    - path: \Process(_total)\Thread Count
      telemetry_metric_name: ThreadCount
      type: double
```

I have added **Thread Count** metric in the file.

I queried the list metrics API but did not found the added metric(Thread count).

Is this the correct way of adding more metrics? If yes, any other flow has to be done in order to fetch metrics through rest api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The developer of the oracle cloud agent here. The configuration is structured this way for future extensibility. Currently, if you add the metric in the config, the agent will try to get the metric from the OS and attempt to submit to the telemetry service backend. The telemetry service will reject the agent's attempt as it only supports a fixed set of metrics, and your is out of that range.

Comment: Thanks Chuan for your inputs. Is there any other way like the documentation says publishing custom metrics [here](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/Content/Monitoring/Tasks/publishingcustommetrics.htm) from the instance?

Comment: Currently, it is not supported in the Oracle Cloud Agent. This is a good feature  request/suggestion in my opinion. I will convey your input to our product management team. We will consider add the support at a later release.